# Multithreading SQL Java

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, jdbc

I have read a lot about how you are meant to use a separate thread for SQL queries as some of them can take large amounts of time, thus delaying your main thread. I can find nothing on how to go about using multiple threads for SQL and best practices of doing so.

I would like to know:

- If I should create a separate thread for each query
- How to manage connections with multiple threads
- How to transfer the query and the results to and from the main thread (never used multiple threads before, sorry)

Comment: The question is extremely vague. What kind of application are you building? A GUI app? A batch? A webapp?

Comment: None of this has anything to do with sql as such. Any basic threading tutorial will get you started.

Comment: I was planning on making a GUI chat app which stores users in a SQL database (original idea, I know...)

Comment: You don't need *multiple* threads for SQL. You need just one, and in that one do all the work you were planning to do anyway.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Is there a decent multithreading tutorial that mentions SQL that you know of?

Comment: Making multiple calls to the same database is more of a database-issue than a java issue. The database will handly multiple users one way or the other, it's not something you want to code in java.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik But for example if the server was half way across the world then you could easily get several hundred milliseconds delay on every query which would delay the rest of the application.

Comment: I said you don't need multiple threads for SQL; I didn't imply you don't need any threads at all for it. You need exactly *one* thread dedicated to SQL queries, distinct from the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/: here's the tutorial you're looking for.

Comment: Sql doesn't matter in terms of threading. You have a service which gets some data from some resource and will take some time. Swap sql for a web service, MSMQ, email response, a printer, an extensive computation routine, makes no difference to the client end. You make a request, you wait for a response. If you make multiple requests, then they need some sort of ID, so you can match a response to it's request. The DBMS already manages multiple requests, well assuming you are using say SQL Server instead of say Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multithread querying in a batch/service application.

1. You can implement a generic set of Callables which take the query string as input (or an identifier or whatever) in the constructor and return a `Future<Integer>` (for update/delete/intert) or `Future<ResultSet>` (select) and run them from a Cached Thread Pool.
2. Connection pooling. Look [Apache dpcp](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) or [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/)
3. I'd say a [TransferQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TransferQueue.html) if you are on Java 7 or ArrayBlockingQueue (or LinkedBlockingQueue) on Java 6. Then have MainThread or another thread handle query results.

If you need some example code just ask :)

P.S. I forgot Apache [DButils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/) has an `AsyncQueryRunner` for purpose ;)

P.P.S. As Marko made me notice it, you don't need a Queue to handle query results in a Desktop application. Just push them into the GUI.

Comment: If using (1), then (3) is not needed. The queue is internal to the Executor Service, and the results are not retrieved at all: the submitted task must post a `Runnable` on the EDT which will *push* the stuff into the GUI.

Comment: Indeed. But at the time I began writing there weren't comments on what kind of software he's trying to do... so I was as generic as the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is just to write it. Only once it is written if you are running into problems should you look into doing things like that.

In most cases simple SQL queries will come back very quickly so in fact you will not need to farm them out to another thread.

If you do have specific queries that take too long then depending on what frameworks etc you are using there are a number of options. (ExecutorService, SwingWorker, etc, etc).

If you do end up going multi-threaded then you should use a connection pool and each thread requests a connection from the pool when it needs one and returns it when it is finished.

There are a number of ways to pass messages between threads. Again it comes down to the framework you are using, Google "myFramework threading tutorial"...